# Printing from Firefox on different printers and setting the page details beforehand

Tags: firefox, printing

I´ve got an odd problem and I have not been able to fix this. I have a computer which is connected to two printers. One is a receipt printer (EPSON TM-U220), and the other one is an impact printer (Epson LX-300+). From Firefox, I need to print on both printers at different moments. So first I print on the receipt printer, then on the impact printer, etc.

However, whenever I first print on the receipt printer, and then go back to the impact printer, the printout is only the width of the page of the receipt printer. That is, the page does not come out properly, just the left part of the page is used for printing and the right part is completely empty, as if I am just printing on the small receipt paper. And there is no way I can tell Firefox that I am printing on this larger printer.

The second print on the impact printer goes fine. Firefox now knows it is printing on the impact printer, and it comes out properly on the full page width. But every first print on the impact printer is using the wrong paper size. How can I fix this?

When I go to PAGE PREVIEW I can not set the printer UNTIL I actually print the page. If I go to PRINT PREVIEW > CONFIGURE PAGE, I can not set the printer I will be using. I can only do so if I go to PRINT PREVIEW > PRINT (here is the dropdown box to set the printer). But I can only set the printer and then click PRINT, or CANCEL. If I click PRINT, then the computer remembers the setting but that page will come our wrong, and when I click cancel it simply does not remember the printer I just set.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify your operating system.  I shall assume Windows.  I propose this:

1. `Choose File > Print ...` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and select your printer.
2. Check "Print to File" and then click OK.
3. Specify a temporary file.

After this the printer should remain selected for the next printout, and by your description the second, real printout should use the correct paper size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could [Reset the printer](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Problems_printing_web_pages#Reset_printer) :

1. Type **about:config** in the Location Bar and press Enter.
   A list of preferences will appear.
2. Type **print.print_printer** for this preference to be selected.
   If it is of the right printer - no need to go on.
3. Right-click that preference and select **Reset**.
4. Restart Firefox (I am not really sure that this last step is required).

Answer (score 1):

Go to control panel. select printer from printers and other devices. Right click on it and select preferences. There you can set default settings for each printer. It will be saved permanently.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug in firefox that has never been fixed.  Basically, you cannot easily use two different size printers at once.  If you have one printer for invoices, for example, and another for shipping labels, one will print wrong. As far as I know there is not a fix for this.  Firefox SHOULD allow you to have several printers of different size paper but that is simply not what it does.  Having to change setting or do additional operations every time you print is not a fix.